# Inserting an Application.worksheetfunction into a cell as a formula

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I want the following function  as an actual formula in excel as opposed to a hardcoded number.

Any tips to make that an actual formula that would enter into the appropriate cell in excel? I want it to be able to actively scan my book to detect when something has been removed.

```
MarkConfirm = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(VLookup(MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 3), HBWS.Range("A:A"), 1, 0), "Not in Book")
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 1).Value = MarkConfirm
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the sheet name to the `TableArray` argument of the function as it's looking at a different sheet.

```
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 3).Address & ", '" & HBWS.Name & "'!" & HBWS.Range("A:A").Address & ",1,0),""Not in Book"")"
```

This will give a formula similar to:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$19, Sheet2!$A:$A,1,0),"Not in Book")
```

Also note when a string literal is used in the formula the quotes are doubled up:  `""Not in Book""`

**Edit (after accepted):**

You could also use the FormulaR1C1 route:

```
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R" & LastMWSR + 1 & "C3,'HBWS_Name'!C1,1,0),""Not In Book"")"
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!

Assuming the address function is just filling in that last bit of defining the relevant sheet?

Comment: `Address` just returns the address of the cell reference.  So  `Cells(1,1).Address` will return $A$1.  There are various arguments you can add to `Address` if you want different absolute/relative references - [Range.Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic example of how to enter a formula into a cell (you can modify this for a range as needed).

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=VLoookup(A1,B:C,2,0)"
```

The basic format is below with the following two variables: "YourRange" and [Formula]

> YourRange.Formula = "=[Formula]"

Comment: I'm trying to do using my defined VBA references, which are going to be static. so I can't just use direct cell references for the first argument.

Comment: You can try to add ". Address" after the named range. Instead of "MWS.Cells," Try "MWS.Address" (in the above format of course)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this - just note, you need to add a worksheet reference in front of the `$A:$A`:

```
Sub Test()

MarkConfirm = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 3) & ", $A:$A, 1, 0), ""Not in Book"")"
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 1).Formula = MarkConfirm

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this myself as a work around and I keep getting "Application-Defined or object-defined error" and I cant for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: @dom176 What is `MWS` and what is `LastMWSR`?

Comment: MWS is a worksheet, and LastMWSR is the last row in the worksheet (the preceding code adds more fields to LastMWSR +1 so technically LastMWSR is the second to last row as this point in the code) .

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Range.Formula` property instead of `Range.Value`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formula-property-excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to replace HBWS with the relevant sheet name.

```
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, 1).Formula = "=IfError(VLookup(C" & LastMWSR + 1 & ",HBWS!A:A, 1, 0), ""Not in Book""))"
```